# Visual Studio – EntityFramework -The Selected Store Procedure Returns no columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

Hi all I have written my query as follows in `sql` which gives me a result, this is my query

```
SELECT Technology,TechDescription, Technology.TechID, COUNT(Question) AS 
  'Totalposts' FROM Technology LEFT JOIN Question ON Question.TechID = Technology.TechID    GROUP BY Technology.TechID, Technology,TechDescription
```

[image]

I just write it in to a stored procedure as follows

```
USE [newForumDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[selectTechQuestions]    Script Date: 01/24/2013 15:06:06 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

create PROCEDURE [dbo].[selectTechQuestions]
 As
  SET FMTONLY OFF
Begin
  SELECT Technology,TechDescription, Technology.TechID, COUNT(Question) AS 
  'Totalposts'

FROM Technology

LEFT JOIN Questions

ON Questions.TechID = Technologies.TechID

GROUP BY Technologies.TechID, Technology,TechDescription
End
```

and added this in to my model, and tried to add an function for the procedure, but I am getting the message as `The selected stored procedure returns no columns` can some one help me

[image]

As per `Habib` requested I tried in both ways i.e

```
1) writing the query in a string and filled the DataSet using SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter which works fine

2) SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "selectTechQuestions";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = con;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

The second one gives me the error `{"Invalid object name 'Questions'."}`

Comment: The `SET FMTONLY OFF` is unusual; I wouldn't expect to see that in use. Can you remove that and see if EF is happier with the proc?

Comment: Try executing your SP in Management Studio and see if you get any result/error

Comment: @HamletHakobyan that is a nice to have, but I would not expect that to interfere with EF in this way.

Comment: `Marc Gravell♦` even then the same result, firstly I write with out that only on my search I found that and included but I am not getting result

Comment: k; can you check `sysobjects` etc to see how many objects exist called `selectTechQuestions` ? Is it possible that EF is looking at a different one (maybe one in your name, rather than `dbo`)? also; if you `sp_helptext selectTechQuestions` - do you get what you expect?

Comment: `Habib` getting the required result with normal query is .net

Comment: Not massively familiar with EF, however, when you add the sproc to your model do you connect to your database server using the same credentials as you use when executing the sproc in management Studio?

Comment: `Marc Gravell` attached image as per you said

Comment: No rows are processed or sent to the client because of the request when SET FMTONLY is turned ON. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx

Comment: @GopeshSharma the *schema* is sent, however. A common usage by ORMs etc is to `SET FMTONLY ON`, exec it, and then turn it off again - although there are often better ways to do that now. But indeed, you shouldn't see `SET FMTONLY` much (if ever) in real code

Comment: So many times before I got same prob, and then I had changes my DB query... I had just set a specific column name for each column of table... I.E **select cola as 'C1', col2 as 'c2'**. Set each column name and then try it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your as

```
SELECT Technology AS 'Technology',TechDescription AS 'TechDescription', Technology.TechID AS 'ID', COUNT(Question) AS 
'Totalposts'

FROM Technology

LEFT JOIN Questions

ON Questions.TechID = Technologies.TechID

GROUP BY Technologies.TechID, Technology,TechDescription
```

So, many time before when I get this type of prob, at that time I had done this.
This is silly, solution but I had come out with my prob, may be It can be help full to you....

**Detail description**
As all we know **select** statement return result as single data-set, even if its from multiple table i.e query like inner join.

> When a data comes form the multiple tables in there is a possibility to over come two different column from different table with same name.

This clause does not made any problem in simple data fetching style i.e as we simply done with **DataAdapter** and **SqlCommand**, but entity framework can't handle this thing, and there fore compiler does not allow query such like which containing **inner join** or multiple table queries.

So to resolve this problem we just have to assign a different name fore each column as I had done here and in this way there will be not at all any problem can cause...

Comment: No problem buddy. Coding is just like sharing, you like my code and I like your code. And If you like my code than buy me bear nothing else... :)

Comment: `Sagar Upadhyay` where do u stay if u are near to my location I will definitely buy ;)

Comment: Sorry, buddy I am in A'Bad, and I am just a student, studying in 2yr of C.E. We can meet on FB my ID is **USAGAR80@GMAIL.COM**...